# OnClick defined in div not firing

Tags: html, asp.net

I define a collection of divs as follows:

```
 foreach (RideOfferInfo offer in rideOfferRes.GetTransportationOffersResult)
 {
    //if (offer.AutoServiceAvailable != "no auto-service" )
    //{
        Session["OfferDivs"] +=
            String.Format(@"<div class=""srv-boxes"" id=""srvbox{0}"" OnClick=""OnChooseRide"" runat=""server"">", i) + Environment.NewLine +
            String.Format(@"<img class=""srv-boxes-img"" src=""{0}"" />", offer.Image) + Environment.NewLine +
            @"<div class=""srv-boxes-details"">" + Environment.NewLine +
            String.Format("<div>{0}</div>", offer.Description) + Environment.NewLine +
            String.Format(@"<div class=""detaisl-rows""><img  src=""passengers.png"" /> {0} PAX</div>", offer.MaxPassengers) + Environment.NewLine +
            String.Format(@"<div class=""srv-boxes-details-pricebox detaisl-rows"">{0} {1}</div>", offer.ClientPrice, offer.Currency) + Environment.NewLine +
            "</div></div>";
    //}
    i++;
}
```

The aspx file calls a function which returns the current session's version of the list.

```
 <div class="cmn1-scroll">
   <%=GetOfferDivs() %>
 </div>
```

The function is defined with the following signature:

```
protected void OnChooseRide(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

When I inspect the div in Chrome DevTools I see

```
<div class="srv-boxes" id="srvbox1" onclick="OnChooseRide" runat="server">
```

and when I click (anywhere in the div) I see an error message in the DevTool console that says "OnChooseRide is not defined".  Is the problem with the function signature? Something else?

Comment: as you have create the `OnChooseRide` is for javascript call, and not for code behind. What is not find is the javascript function and you see that error.

Comment: Is it not possible to attach a .net codebehind call to a div?

Comment: not that way, not by rendering text. Maybe if you make a trick. Use a real asp.net link button, see what code use there (a javascript call) and left it on page hidden with css, then render the same javascript call on your divs.

Comment: other asp.net way is to use a repeater, there place an asp.net control that call the code behind

Comment: I think a repeater is the way to go. Building up your page's HTML like this is just a bad idea all around.